# Suggestion of dataset

Tags: dataset, data, bigdata

I am implementing my own deep network, but I am not so good at calculus so my network only works for binary data in the moment. I have been searching for big tabular datasets that are for binary classification. I could not find it, so I want to know if you guys know any dataset with this characteristics, any suggestions?

Comment: What does calculus have to do with implementing a neural network? Certainly there’s calculus going on behind the scenes, but you don’t need to know that to code the model.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how big the data you need but this link has data for binary classification. https://www.kaggle.com/tags/binary-classification